# Zend Database Table getrow

Tags: database, zend-framework, fetch

I have a table of serial keys

```
+----+---------------------+------+
| id | product_key         | used |
+----+---------------------+------+
|  1 | 3C45-GH76-9V74-HLKJ |    1 |
|  2 | REDF-6KI9-00IU-4867 |    0 |
|  3 | 1111-1111-1111-1111 |    0 |
|  4 | 2222-2222-2222-2222 |    0 |
|  5 | 3333-3333-3333-3333 |    0 |
+----+---------------------+------+
```

I would like to get one row record that `used=0` using zend framework. Then change to `used=1` if that `product_key` had select.

I am confuse using Zend.

I think it's something like that, but how to assign "1" into used if that product key had been select?

```
$productKey = $this->_helper->model('ProductKeys')->fetchOne('SELECT * from product_keys WHERE used=0 LIMIT 1');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear a way to do it in a single simple query. Also, *fetchOne* only gets the first column of the first record. That helper would return just the ID, and not the product_key.

**Option 1:** 
Modify your ProductKeys model to get the key and set it as used:

```
class My_Model_ProductKeys extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
...
function getKeyAndMarkUsed()
{
  $select = $this->select();
  $select->where('used=?',1)->limit(1)->order('ID');
  $keyRow = $this->fetchRow();
  if ($keyRow){
    $this->update(array('used'=>1),'id='.$keyRow->ID);
    return $keyRow->id;
  }
  else{
    //no keys left! what to do??? Create a new key?
    throw new Exception('No keys left!');
  }
}
```

Then you would just:

```
$productKey = $this->_helper->model('ProductKeys')->getKeyAndMarkUsed();
```

**Option 2**: 
Make a database procedure to do the above functionality and call that instead.